# Will the plugin installed in Jenkins automatically ben installed into slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For example, I have a Jenkins Master and two Jenkins slaves for two different projects, one project needs to use Github plugin, so I will install Github plugin in Master. But it is slave which will actually use the Github plugin, so does this means plugin will automatically be installed into slave??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins only need to be installed on the Jenkins master; you don't need to worry about anything there.

But if you're using Git, you need to ensure that Git is installed on each of the build machines where you want to check out code.  You can set up Git to be installed automatically via the main Jenkins settings, or you can install Git manually, e.g. via a package manager.